# Random randint def() for storage variables

Tags: python, function, random

I'm trying to make a list where each time a random item from the list is chosen it gives the number to the define of r() which will take the number and give a random number between the values defined to the tenths place. The lists im using are for storage variables that i'm using for items for a game, though i feel there's a good chance i may want to modify these variables to tweak the stats of something, and I would like to try and make it easier to find the item and variables by having a short name of a define and the numbers such as r(1,2), instead of having ((random.randint(1x10,2x10)/10) for every item in the list. Although iv found whenever the same item is picked from the list it always gives the same output for the number, as an example if the list picks the item r(1,2) and runs through the define r() it might give a number of 1.3. The second time it picks the same item though instead of giving a different number it only gives the same number of 1.3

```
import random

def r(start,end):
    answ = (random.randint(start*10,end*10)/10)
    return answ

itemname =        ['name1','name2','name3','name4','name5']
itemvariable =    [r(1,2), r(1,3), r(3,5), r(1,6), r(6,7) ]

print(random.choice(itemname),random.choice(itemvariable))
print(random.choice(itemname),random.choice(itemvariable))
print(random.choice(itemname),random.choice(itemvariable))
```

example of current output(assuming random.choice() theoretically always picks first item of each list)

name1 1.3

name1 1.3

name1 1.3

example of desired output(assuming random.choice() theoretically always picks first item of each list)

name1 1.7

name1 1.2

name1 1.8

​

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Odd, your code works fine on my machine. Perhaps it had something to do with the seed.

Comment: Note that you call `r` at the time of creating `itemvariable` and store return values. Then when you print, you always print the same value from list. Print `itemvariable` to see the values in the list

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I didn't realize that

Answer (score 0):

I believe buran probably gave you the reason that the output is not what you were expecting in his comment, but didn't go so far as to provide a true solution to achieve your desired effect. It really wouldn't be that hard to modify your code to produce the expected output, however. Instead of storing the result of a call to `r(start, end)` in itemvariable, simply store the desired range as a tuple. Then, when calling `print`, use the unpacking operator (`*`) to pass that range to `r(start, end)`:

```
itemname = [ 'name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5' ]
itemvariable = [ (1,2), (1,3), (3,5), (1,6), (6,7) ]
print(random.choice(itemname), r(*(random.choice(itemvariable))))
print(random.choice(itemname), r(*(random.choice(itemvariable))))
print(random.choice(itemname), r(*(random.choice(itemvariable))))
```

I don't have a Python interpreter in front of me at the moment, so I'm not 100% certain that the parentheses are necessary around `random.choice(itemvariable)`, but while they don't clarify the code any they won't hurt. The upshot is that the call to `random.choice(itemvariable)` will return a tuple containing the desired range for your call to `r(...)`, and the `*` will unpack the first and second value to populate the first and second arguments. Since each print will call `r` separately, you will (or well, you *probably* will, since it's random) get a different value each time.